# rstudio - removing the memory limit

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server, memory-limit

I’m trying to run some modeling (random forest, using caret) in rstudio server 1.1.423 (with R version 3.4.4, running on an Ubuntu 16.04 server), and it comes back with the following error:

`Error: protect(): protection stack overflow`

This error doesn't come up if I run the same analysis in an interactive R session. I seem to recall that in the past (in rstudio server running an older version of R) was able to resolve this error by issuing `memory.limit(500000)` in an interactive rstudio server session, but these days this comes back with:

```
> memory.limit(500000)
[1] Inf
Warning message:
'memory.limit()' is Windows-specific
```

A solution that works and that I use routinely is to run my analysis from a script, like `Rscript --max-ppsize=500000 --vanilla /location/of/the/script.R`, but that’s not what I want to do, as in this particular case I need to run the analysis interactively.

I’ve also tried adding `R_MAX_VSIZE=500000` at the end of my ~/.profile, or `rsession-memory-limit-mb=500000` into /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf, as well as putting `options(expressions = 5e5)` in my ~/.Rprofile, or running `options(expressions = 5e5)` in an interactive rstudio server session. No luck so far, the “protect()” error keeps on popping up.

Any ideas as to how to remove the memory limit in rstudio server?

Comment: From `?memory.limit`, it is *"used to manage the total memory allocation on Windows. On other platforms these are stubs which report infinity with a warning."* You should not expect its behavior on non-windows platforms. I suggest your problem with `protect` is rooted elsewhere. From what package do you expect `protect` to be exported? It is not in base R (on windows or linux, at least).

Comment: Amazingly, earlier I managed to paste in the wrong error message. What I'm actually seeing when I try to run the analysis in RStudio Server is `Error: protect(): protection stack overflow`, as now corrected in the post. I don't get this error if I run the same analysis in an R session initiated with `R --max-ppsize=500000` or via an analysis script: `Rscript --max-ppsize=500000 --vanilla /location/of/the/script.R`.

Comment: I tried to find a way to use the `--max-ppsize` flag in RStudio Server, ended up finding the following [post](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200650343-RStudio-Server-0-98-Deprecated-rsesssion-ulimit-options) that seems to indicate that the ability to do so was deprecated and is now only available in the Pro version.